# fscanf help: how to check for formatting

Tags: c, string, buffer, scanf

So the current function is supposed to see anything stored between two pound signs (#abc# should give back abc), but if I want to error check to see if there's a pound sign missing, or there's nothing between the pound signs, or that the length of the string in between the two pound signs is greater than a certain number of characters, do I use the fscanf function to do that?

Here's what the fscanf code looks like:

```
if (fscanf(fp, " %c%[^#]%c", &start, buffer, &end) == 3) {
    return strdup(buffer);      
} else { 
    return NULL;
```

}

Comment: Your fscanf looks fine. One tidbit though, you could try the format specifier: `" %c%100[^#]%c"` to make sure the user doesn't input more characters than you can handle (obviously replace 100 with the size of your `buffer`).

Answer (score 1):

> do I use the fscanf function to do that?

No, you don't. Using the `scanf()` family of functions is *very rarely* a good idea.

```
char buf[0x1000];

// expect leading `#'
int ch = fgetc(fp);
if (ch != '#') {
    puts("Error, missing # at beginning of input");
    exit(-1);
}

// read until terminating `#' or until the buffer is exhausted
char *p = buf;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '#' && p - buf < sizeof(buf)) {
    *p++ = ch;
}

// expect terminating `#'
if (ch != '#') {
    puts("Error, missing # at end of input");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Why so ? The `fscanf` in the question text looks fine. Checking return status and all. Also, I'll call a "citation needed" on the "using scanf is rarely good" part.

Comment: @cnicutar Because `scanf()` is evil. Better be safe, not? It may work in one particular case, but what if something changes in the format of the input, etc.? Just like nobody uses `while(scanf("%s", buf) == 1)` for getting user input.

Comment: @cnicutar And even you, in your own comment to OP's question, pointed out a possible vulnerability (buffer overrun). It's easy to forget and leave out that `100` from the format string.

Comment: It's certainly not evil. Had it truly been evil (the way `gets` was for example) it would have been removed from the standard. But it's a perfectly ok function, you just need to know how it works.

Comment: @cnicutar Well... and what if I say, "`fgets()` is not evil, if it had been, it wouldn't even have been included in the standard originally"... Also, I hope you believe at least the other one (Jonathan Leffler) who shares this opinion.

Comment: I don't see how the `fgets` part fits in. And appealing to authority rarely works for me: I prefer hard solid arguments.

Comment: The problem with `fscanf()` and `scanf()` — as distinct from `sscanf()` — is that it is very difficult to use correctly in general, and very easy to use incorrectly. For simple cases where you get properly formatted data and won't have to deal with invalid data, and where the error reporting doesn't have to be accurate, then you can use it. When you need accurate control, especially for error reporting, it is close to a disaster when anything goes wrong. Using `sscanf()` lets you report errors accurately; it can still be misused.  Overflows on string buffers are one way in which that happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it's really easy to miss one very slight detail, even if you otherwise know the correct usage. Being explicit in your code doesn't hurt, and safety should be one of the most important considerations.

Comment: @cnicutar "I prefer hard solid arguments" - Apparently, my arguments didn't convince you to any extent...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good points :-) I too prefer using `sscanf` on a string where I can go back and forth as I please but maintain (weasel-wording myself out of it) that `fscanf` isn't evil: it is perfectly possible to use it correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't choose 'evil' for the function.  I might choose 'evil' for the people who make beginners learn it first.  I think it is cruel to teach such an arcane function to novices.  It is bad enough for non-novices.  Can you distinguish between `%99c` and `%99s`?  Most people can't (many aren't aware that you can use a length with `%c`).  And where does a scan set (`%99[^\n]`) fit in?  Etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Once again, good points: `fscanf` certainly isn't easy to use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "I might choose 'evil' for the people who make beginners learn it first." - **Exactly.**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with the zero-characters case, then probably `fscanf()` is not the right tool.  There's a reasonable argument that `fscanf()` is seldom the correct tool; you'd do better with `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

In this case, I'd collect lines until there's one that's not blank (since that's what the `fscanf()` does), and then search for the `#` symbols with `strchr()`:

```
char line[4096];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
{
    if (strspn(line, " \t\n") == strlen(line))
        continue;
    char *hash1 = strchr(line, '#');
    if (hash1 == 0)
        ...error no hashes...
    else
    {
        char *hash2 = strchr(hash1+1, '#');
        if (hash2 == 0)
            ...second hash is missing...
        if (hash2 - hash1 > MAX_PERMITTED_STRING_LEN)
            ...too long a string...
        *hash2 = '\0';
        char *res = strdup(hash1);
    }
}
```