# Reading in alphabet characters only - C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm opening a text file and want to read in the alphabet words only. 
So for example if I had a text file with "Hello-World Hey". I'd like to read the words "Hello", "World", "Hey".

The problem is I'm not sure what the "format specifier" should be for this output. I've tried countless combinations but none worked as hoped.

```
FILE *fpin; 
char str[50];

while (fscanf(fpin, "%s[a-zA-Z]", str) != EOF) {
    // do something with str
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, who keeps on telling the C novices that scanf is a good idea?

Comment: @Kay I'm a C novice myself, what is a better option and why is scanf a bad idea?  (I realize the question sounds adversarial, but I actually want to know)

Comment: @Kay Professors, books,..., it is powerful if used correctly.

Comment: Yes, scanf is a very good tool if used correctly (see 
Jonathan's answer). But if professionals bothered to tell novices to do bound checking too, it would be an even better tool.

Comment: Just for clarification, this is for an assignment where only the standard C library is allowed.

Comment: See the comments (mainly) to [`fscanf()` help: how to check for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985203/fscanf-help-how-to-check-for-formatting/) for a discussion of some of the problems with using `fscanf()` etc.  You'll find other such diatribes elsewhere on SO, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're nearly there; the scan set should be used, but the scan set does not have an `s` conversion too.

```
while (fscanf(fpin, "%49[a-zA-Z]", str) == 1) {
```

The 49 prevents buffer overflows (and yes, it has to be one less than the dimension of the array).

Of course, this works for the first word; you then need to skip over the non-word characters before you can read the next word, so you might have:

```
while (fscanf(fpin, "%49[a-zA-Z]", str) == 1)
{
    ...do something with word in str...
    if (fscanf(fpin, "%49[^a-zA-Z]", str) != 1)
        ...decide what to do...
        ...but remember one problem might be that the 'word' was too long...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly new to programming myself, but maybe this is what you are looking for.
Hope it helps.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int i = 0;
FILE *fpin; 
char c, str[50];

while ((c = fgetc(fpin)) != EOF)
{
    if(isalpha(c))
        str[i++] = c;

}
str[i] = '\0';
// do something with str
```

Comment: This is wrong , checking EOF with a char , not null terminating the array.

Comment: Remember that `fgetc()` and its relatives return an `int`, not a `char`.  That's because they have to identify the 256 possible character values (assuming 8-bit `char` types) and a distinct value, EOF.  If `char` is unsigned, then your EOF test will never be true (you won't spot when EOF occurs).  If `char` is signed, then you will misdetect EOF on some valid character, often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, 0xFF.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler There is a wide char variant of fgetc called fgetwc (and a WEOF instead of EOF). Although I am not certain that is what you had in mind. I tried this on my machine, it seems to work just fine. Anyway, you have over 200k rep - my knowledge is hardly comparable with yours.

Comment: I was discussing the code you show — wide characters etc are a different problem.  The older standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) says in §7.19.7.1 _The `fgetc()` function:_ 'If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).'